# How do Shardblades change shape and size?

Tags: cosmere, stormlight-archive

Live Shardblades can change shape and size based on the needs of the bearer. But if they are a manifestation of a Spren moving fully into the physical realm, how can they change size/mass?

Comment: A wizard did it.

Comment: Why would they have mass before they were physical?  Heck, they may not even have mass anyway, it's not like swords that big are normally liftable.

Comment: Mild spoilers for Words of Radiance and Edgedancer...this isn't an answer to how they do it, but the shard weapon isn't the only example of a spren changing their basic form. Lift's spren Wyndle changes his form to vines to help climb.

Comment: Well, if you'd read carefully, it's easy to notice that they *aren't*  fully in the physical realm when they change.

Comment: @Alarion his form IS vines he doesnt change them. also those vines are mostly in the cognitive realm but lift is also partially in the cognitive so she can touch him

Comment: @Radhil they are Investiture in the cognitive, which is energy. when they move to the physical and take a form, they are condensing from energy into matter

Comment: Investiture isn't exactly energy. In Shadesmar spren are usually more "material" then in physical realm.

Answer (score 2):

Spren are not primarily physical beings - they are "cognitive entities" according to the Ars Arcanum. They do not have a fixed size or mass in the first place (compare the Interlude where ardents are measuring flamespren, or Syl's various forms).

Shardblades' mass is the Investiture (essentially "magic power/essence") of the spren turned into matter. See this question [Are Shardblades "God Metal"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/204033/are-shardblades-god-metal?rq=1) for more.