# Can shard metal be affected by Allomancy?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, stormlight-archive

Can a shard blade or shard plate be affected by Allomancy and/or be burned or have attributes stored in it?

Comment: According to this, yes for at least Shardblades. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/204033/are-shardblades-god-metal

Comment: What allomancy? You wouldn't be able to do anything to them under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, shardblade and shardplate could be affected by allomancy.

There are some caveats to this though.

For starters, it would be very *difficult* to actually do.  Investiture resists investiture; and the stronger the investiture, the stronger it resists.

Something like shardblade or shardplate are pretty far into the invested side of the spectrum; according to Brandon Sanderson, they are essentially pure investiture, so using allomancy on them would require you to have a lot of power in the trait.  See the following WoB for an example on steel pushing/iron pulling:

> **Questioner:**
>   Could you use steel or iron to Push or Pull off Shardblades or Shardplate?
>
> **Brandon Sanderson:**
>   Anything that's Invested resists, the more Invested it is the more it resists.
>
> **Questioner:**
>   Okay, so you could technically--
>
> **Brandon Sanderson:**
>   Yes.
>
> **Questioner:**
>   --if it was not charged?
>
> **Brandon Sanderson:**
>   Well-- Certain objects just have more Investiture and are more purely of the Investiture. A Shardblade's going to be really hard, but it's possible, it's just going to be really, really hard. Even more hard than an absolutely full Feruchemical metalmind because the Shardblade is being created directly out of the Investiture, it's basically all Investiture, it's not a metal that is Invested. It's going to be real hard.
>
> [source](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/6/#e247)

Burning them would be similar; and that is covered well by Adamant in this [related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/204033/are-shardblades-god-metal).  The important connections to take from that are that shardblades and plate are godmetal, and therefore we would expect them to be able to be used, like how we've seen Lerasium, Atium, Trell's metal, and ettmetal all used in the metallic arts.  The difference with shardblades and plate is that they are far more invested, enough that they have sapience, so using the metallic arts on them would require you to have enough power to overcome those barriers that the investiture adds.

Comment: Blades aren't more invested then atium or lerasium, but they have Identity of they own - much like one can't use sb's metalmind, trying to burn such metal isn't possible.

Comment: @Mithoron There's nothing about Identity that prevents you from burning metal.  It prevents you from using a full metalmind for compounding; but you can still access the allomantic powers of the metal when you burn it.  You just feel an extra reserve of the feurochemical store that you are unable to access.  There's no _definitive_ statement about burning a shardblade or shardplate.  We can only theorize based on what we know, and we know that shardblades are godmetal, and we have evidence that godmetals are part of the allomantic arts.

Comment: Also, most of the evidence and other posts I can find agree with the notion that a shardblade at least has more investiture than a regular godmetal.  They are comparing it to a near-full atium metalmind for example.

Comment: Huh, these are interesting points, gonna check them out maybe...

Comment: Author did make similar point to mine though https://wob.coppermind.net/events/85/#e2901

Comment: @Mithoron I'm not sure exactly what that WoB is actually trying to even imply.  In Mistborn when Vin burns Sazed's earring, from what I remember she still feels the allomantic power like normal. She also feels the feruchemical power she can't touch.  He might be saying you would get the regular allomantic power from Nightblood's metal (which is who knows what), but you wouldn't get any of his immense power because it is all keyed to Nightblood.